# How to split a string with multiple patterns in perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I want to split a string with multiple patterns:

ex.

```
my $string= "10:10:10, 12/1/2011";

my @string = split(/firstpattern/secondpattern/thirdpattern/, $string);

foreach(@string) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

I want to have an output of:

```
10
10
10
12
 1
2011
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a [character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Using-character-classes) in the regex delimiter to match on a set of possible delimiters.

```
my $string= "10:10:10, 12/1/2011";
my @string = split /[:,\s\/]+/, $string;

foreach(@string) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

**Explanation**

- The pair of slashes `/.../` denotes the regular expression or pattern to be matched.
- The pair of square brackets `[...]` denotes the character class of the regex.
- Inside is the set of possible characters that can be matched: colons `:`, commas `,`, any type of space character `\s`, and forward slashes `\/` (with the backslash as an escape character).
- The `+` is needed to match on 1 or more of the character immediately preceding it, which is the entire character class in this case. Without this, the comma-space would be considered as 2 separate delimiters, giving you an additional empty string in the result.

Comment: Worked perfectly well! Thanks. Btw, do you mind to explain this code? /[:,\s\/]+/

Comment: Thank you for the additional input, that simply explains everything! :D

Comment: I know it is an old thread, but I am wondering how I should add []() to the list of delimiters? It seems to get rid of the []() when I just add it there.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul, Add a backslash in front of each of those, just like I have for the slash above

Answer (score 6):

Wrong tool!

```
my $string = "10:10:10, 12/1/2011";
my @fields = $string =~ /([0-9]+)/g;
```

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm sorry, I didn't know there is another approach on it.

Comment: @quinekxi, No need to apologise, you didn't do anything wrong. A good reply usually comes from considering the bigger picture. Questions are often [too specific](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem).

Comment: Thanks though for giving me something to think of and consider another solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can split on non-digits;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my $string= "10:10:10, 12/1/2011";
say for split /\D+/, $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

If numbers are what you want, extract numbers:

```
my @numbers = $string =~ /\d+/g;
say for @numbers;
```

Capturing parentheses are not required, as specified in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Matching-in-list-context):

> The /g modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching
>   as many times as possible within the string. How it behaves depends on
>   the context. In list context, it returns a list of the substrings
>   matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression. **If
>   there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched
>   strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern.**

Comment: I hadn't known about the behavior you highlighted, thanks, and good for golf too!

Comment: I didn't know I could use this kind of approach. Good thinking! Thank you so much!

Comment: @quinekxi You're welcome. `split` is a very nice tool, but works best with uniform delimiters, I feel. In this case, the common element is numbers, so it's easier to work with them.

Comment: @TLP Yes, actually I used this approach but I didn't mark  this as the answer just to comply on the original question. Anyway, thanks for your idea. I am glad I've got such great ideas from strangers you like.

Comment: @quinekxi Many of my answers are not the solutions the OPs asked for, but the one I thought they really wanted. Your question was really "How do I best extract the numbers from this string?" So that's the answer you got. :)

Comment: @TLP Sorry for giving a wrong question to the problem I have. I'm still on the learning process of being a programmer-wanna-be. I like you to be my mentor sort of. LOL, its just a comment. :D

Comment: @quinekxi You're always welcome to post new questions. It is a good way to learn.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $string= "10:10:10, 12/1/2011";

my @string = split(m[(?:firstpattern|secondpattern|thirdpattern)+], $string);

my @string = split(m[(?:/| |,|:)+], $string);

print join "\n", @string;
```

Comment: `/| |,|:` better written as `[/ ,:]`

Comment: @TLP, is it? IIRC alternations get compiled into a trie internally, does a character class? Not saying you are wrong, really a question.

Comment: @JoelBerger I don't know about the internals, but I think it's more readable. Here's a benchmark: `perl -wE "use Benchmark qw(cmpthese); $a=qq(10:10:10, 12/1/2011); cmpthese(100000, { Piped => sub { my @r = split (m[(?:/| |,|:)+], $a); }, Class => sub  { my @r = split (m[(?:[/ ,:])+], $a); } });"` `Piped 142450/s    --  -27% // Class 194175/s   36%    --` Looks like character class is 36% faster.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that the m delimiter was brackets. Strange that it didn't complain. Well, with `m##`, the results go up to 45% faster.

Comment: This answer is more general - it can be used with entire words as well

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original question:
you were looking for [the `|` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/perlre.html#Metacharacters):

```
my $string = "10:10:10, 12/1/2011";

my @string = split(/:|,\s*|\//, $string);

foreach(@string) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

But, as the other answers point out, you can often improve on that with further simplifications  or generalizations.

Comment: Why are you linking to the 5.10.0 version of the page, instead of the version agnostic http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Metacharacters ?

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: Because that was the first one Google gave me, and I'm using 5.10 myself, and portability can potentially be an issue, and I didn't realize there was a version-agnostic version.  Thanks for supplying the link.

Answer (score 1):

As you're parsing something that is rather obviously a date/time, I wonder if it would make more sense to use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/release/DateTime-Format-Strptime) to parse it into a DateTime object.